# Very Low Performance for same binaries built using VS2017 (Platform Toolkit v141) as compared to VS2013(Platform Toolkit v120)

Tags: windows, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2017

I am working on a project/product (C++) that was recently migrated to VS2017.

After the migration, overall product performance dropped down to around 40%. The product uses various REST API calls, HTTPs calls as well as Normal interface calls. We had done some code changes as well in order to make the product compatible.

We are suspecting the platform toolkit (v141) is causing the problems. Because, we tested with two set of binaries for the exact same code, one built using v120 (in VS2013) and other using v141(in VS2017) Platform Toolkit. The one built with v141 had the performance problems.

We checked also by disabling the optimizations in VS2017, still no luck.

It would be helpful if anyone here has the prior knowledge as for why this performance degradation is happening.

The Info here is less I know, If additional info is needed I can provide it.

The product build environment:

VS2017 Version 15.7

Optimized for Max Speed or Minimum size.

Comment: do you use the [Spectre versions](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2018/04/09/spectre-mitigation-changes-in-visual-studio-2017-version-15-7-preview-3/) or the normal ones?

Comment: We use normal versions only..